# How to align @visx Hierarchy Tree view nodes on the top & root node on the top left

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, d3.js, tree, visx

I am using VISX and example implementation is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/airbnb/visx/tree/master/packages/visx-demo/src/sandboxes/visx-linktypes

I want to achieve the UI, where root node is on the top left and all children nodes in each level align top to bottom

Something like this
[image]

Comment: I think you can build a desired tree using d3 only (without libraries like visx)

Comment: I think d3js is following reingold-tilford algorithm to place the children evenly spaced around the parent. But is there any js algorithm to achieve above